# Get rid of a previously set width

Tags: html, css

I have a width that is set as:

```
body {
    width: 980px;
}
```

However, on one page, I need to have the width fit the page (it is a big table that should be as big as the browser allows. How would I remove the previously-set width? I tried doing:

```
body {
    width: none!important;
}
```

But no luck. What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use width: auto !important

```
body {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: If it works without `!important` leave that bit out. `!important` should be reserved for very specific use-cases and I'm not sure this is one of them.

Comment: Yes, indeed, always better to not use !important